# Is there a way to find out what files are written when running apk file on a PC android emulator?

Tags: android, plugins, virus

My problem is dealing with a kind of malware .apk file. The .apk is packed into a plugin-framework called virtual app. So when you run the .apk, it will firstly unpack another encrypted .apk file in its asset. It used AES to decrypt, but the key generation is obfuscated. To make it easy I want to run it on a PC emulator and try to find out its unpacked .apk file, is there a way to do this?

The code to decrypt file inside asset is:

```
    localObject2 = paramActivity.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
    assertsToSd((String)localObject2, paramActivity);
    localObject3 = (String)localObject2 + File.separator + aname;
    localObject1 = localObject3;
    String str1 = (String)localObject2 + File.separator + 0 + aname;
    localObject2 = (String)localObject2 + File.separator + (0 + 1) + aname;
    String str2 = create(paramActivity).substring(0, 16);
    if (i == 0)
    {
      Catalog.decFile((String)localObject3, str1, str2);
      new File((String)localObject3).delete();
      Tools.downloadFile(new File(str1), new File((String)localObject2));
      new File(str1).delete();
    }
```

The decrypt file function:

```
    public static boolean decFile(String sourceFile, String destFile, String speed) {
    File s = new File(sourceFile);
    File d = new File(destFile);
    if (!s.exists()) {
        return false;
    }
    if (d.exists()) {
        d.delete();
    }
    try {
        d.createNewFile();
        return c.decrypt(speed, s, d);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

The purpose of running a apk inside another container like apk is its actual code can be encrypted and skip being detected by anti-virus software and moreover it can install any other apk remotely inside without any notice from user.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved this problem by installing android x86 virtual machine, and run app in it. Then I mount the vmdk file in Linux and copied the extracted .apk file.

By the way, the original .apk decrypts its asset .apk file by AES, the key is generated with taking first 16 bytes of package signature and use a customized md5 to generate the key for AES and after decryption, it runs it inside virtualapp framework.

Moreover, if you download the .apk from the website multiple times, it will give you different .apk files with different signatures. This bypassed virus scans.